# Meaning of 'à quoi'?

Tags: sens, à

I came across this passage in Boris Vian's 'Les Fourmis' (1949):

> Il paraît que ça commence à sentir la fin. Je ne sais pas à quoi ils voient ça, mais je voudrais tâcher de m'en sortir le plus commodément possible.

I don't recognise the use of the words 'à quoi' in the second sentence and can't find it as a phrase in the dictionary.

Comment: This is *like*: *à quoi c'est dû?* That is due to what ? à quoi refers to the means for or of something. Due to what are they seeing that? Though I'd use "I don't know how they're seeing that". A quoi tu vois ça? What makes you see it that way.

Comment: @Earendelle Pour expliquer des structures, les comparaisons sont fréquentes. Et puis, complément en anglais c'est object, pas "complement".

Comment: @Lambie My point is it's not as typical for _voir_ to have two objects to mean what we have here. I don't find it run of the mill like your comment seemingly implies. Thanks btw for complement.

Comment: @Earendelle I did not say it was run of the mill at all. I tried to show how it might work in terms of English.

Answer (score 6):

***À quoi*** represents the signs that lead them to see/believe the end was close.

The meaning is something like: "I don't know what makes them think that."

Answer (score 5):

The meaning has been established in another [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50184). I believe the meaning is more about *perception* than sight indeed, as in *finding something* or *coming to a conclusion about something* and this would match a specific construction for the verb [*voir*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voir) (2e, I. C.):  *Voir quelquechose à quelquechose* where you have a second object (indirect) introduced with the prepostion *à* and it feels to me a bit like "from". *They're finding it's the beginning of the end from what* i.e. the first something is the conclusion from the preceding sentence in the text and the second one is literally not known. I think in this very instance the second object is made up of the preposition *à* with an interrogation word (*quoi*) and is anteposed. It is only loosely connected with "je ne sais pas" whereas the whole "à quoi ils voient ça" is the object for that.

Comment: Les commentaires sont les bienvenus j'ai un peu de difficulté avec la grammaire de ce truc-là. vraiment intéressant par ailleurs.

Comment: Oui. *— À quoi  ils voient ça ? —  Ils voient ça **au** fait que [...]* ou *— Ils voient ça **à** la baisse d'intensité [...]* etc.

Comment: @jlliagre Si tu parcoures LBU14@281b un moment donné, est-ce que ça participe de ça i.e. marquant l'appartenance, équivalent d'une conjonctive avec le verbe avoir ?? Ils donnent « Je ne TROUVE qu'un défaut À CET OUVRAGE (Ac. 1935) ->• Je trouve que cet
ouvrage n'a qu'un défaut. ». Après au moins un café à essayer de faire entrer la phrase de la question dans ce moule-là j'ai pas été capable, remarque c'est peut-être comme avec le bonhomme pendu de sudoku avec les ronds de couleurs là.